# Sonarqube error with .dotnet build

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I created a sonar build in teamcity but every time I run it I get the following error. How to find which file is breaking build?

Sonar 5.1.2
TC 9.1.3

Build is executed with sonar-runner.

```
`[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.314 ERROR - 
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR - Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 244, position 78.
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue()
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value()
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
[17:18:06][Step 1/1] 17:18:06.342 ERROR -    at SonarQube.CSharp.CodeAnalysis.Runner.Program.Main(String[] args)`

`[17:18:14][Step 1/1] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
[17:18:14][Step 1/1] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[17:18:14][Step 1/1] org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
[
[17:18:14][Step 1/1] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The .NET analyzer failed with exit code: -532462766


[17:18:15][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1`

[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.758 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.758 INFO  - Index files
[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.759 INFO  - Excluded sources: 
[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.759 INFO  -   **/?eference.cs
[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.759 INFO  -   **/*.?esigner.cs
[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.759 INFO  -   **/*.xml
[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.759 INFO  -   **/*.config
[11:36:55][Step 1/1] 11:36:55.759 INFO  -   CashMonitor.cs
```

Comment: please specify excludes and add more logs before error occurs (hide sensitive information).